# Linux Renaming files in a folder where the names is ab1.jpg, ab2.jpg, ab10.jpg etc

Tags: linux, bash, batch-rename

The order of the files is determined by a number that can be embedded in the filename, but sometimes in the beginning of the name e.g.
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file10.txt
file11.txt
etc..
or 
1.txt
2.txt
10.txt etc..

The renaming should result in names like...
file01.txt
file02.txt
file03.txt
file10.txt
etc...

It is important that file1.txt will be file01.txt and not file10.txt to be file01.txt.

I think the filenames have to be formatted before renaming. I have no idea of how to do that on the command line, maybe it must be done by a script but I hope not.

The command should be given the number of digits we should have in the final name. If its possible to use a formatting string we also could give the position where we have the number(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the perl `rename` utility:

```
rename -n 's/\d+/sprintf("%02d", $&)/e' *.txt
```

Result would be:

```
$ ls
file10.txt  file1.txt  file2.txt  file3.txt

$ rename -n 's/\d+/sprintf("%02d", $&)/e' *.txt
rename(file1.txt, file01.txt)
rename(file2.txt, file02.txt)
rename(file3.txt, file03.txt)
```

If that looks good, remove the `-n` dry-run flag.

Note that the format string to `sprintf` determines the "width" of the zero-padding, so if you were dealing with filenames that get into the triple digits, you'd want to change that to `"%03d"`, etc..

```
$ ls
file100.txt  file10.txt  file1.txt  file2.txt  file3.txt

$ rename -n 's/\d+/sprintf("%03d", $&)/e' *.txt
rename(file10.txt, file010.txt)
rename(file1.txt, file001.txt)
rename(file2.txt, file002.txt)
rename(file3.txt, file003.txt)
```

Comment: This works whatever the number position in the filename.

Comment: Ok, looks good at first but in the directory I have 13 files numbered from 1 to 13 but I just get the first 9 files renamed. I can't see where this limit is set? Of course, how stupid of me, as the result is 2 digits there's no need for renaming.

Comment: @larand That's because the files with 10-13 need no modification, yes? You wouldn't zero-pad those.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I was just prepared to see all files processed as it have been in all other examples I tried. Thank's a lot!